# Launching an activity from the custom list

Tags: android

I have got installed apps in one activity, I have another activity which lists only the apps that were checked in the first activity. There are three problems:
Fist is it shows something like this in the second activity
[image: Hello]

It shows the apps like this instead of their names and icons. What can I do for that?

Second as you can see it shows duplicates. I dont have any checkbox so I dont know how to remove the app if the app is selected twice in the first activity

Third I am using this to launch activity selected in the above image

```
    Intent newIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
    startActivity(newIntent);
```

It just starts my first activity. What do I need to write in space of getPackageName() ?

If needed I will post the code for first and second activity.
Thanks.

Here is my AppInfoAdapter

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<?> mListAppInfo;
private PackageManager mPackManager;

public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List<?> list, PackageManager pm) {
    mContext = c;
    mListAppInfo = list;
    mPackManager = pm;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListAppInfo.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListAppInfo.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get the selected entry
    ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);

    // reference to convertView
    View v = convertView;

    // inflate new layout if null
    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lvrowlayout, null);
    }

    // load controls from layout resources
    ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    TextView tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvPkgName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);

    // set data to display
    ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
    tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
    tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);

    // return view
    return v;
  }
```

Here islvrowlayout

```
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
 android:padding="5dip" 
 >

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
  android:scaleType="center"
/>

<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="0dip"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"    
 >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvName"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"         
  />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvPack"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"         
  />

  </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ListView? Could you post your Adapter? It seems like you aren't override the ListView's adapter's count or the layout in which you can set a picture, etc.

You could create a layout for the row like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
     .... />

    <TextView
     .... />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then in your ListView Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater vi  (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);

//Set image and text view here

}
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. As I said the apps are stored in an ArrayList A which is passed through bundle and accessed in another activity. So should I set a.appName = (textview) and a.icon = (ImageView)?

Comment: could you post lvrowlayout.xml?

Comment: is there a reason you have to pass the apps? if you're just an image and two strings I would suggest creating an object that stores those and then passing that through to the listview.

Comment: Yes I am building an app where only apps selected by user will be shown so i need to be able to pass the apps nd launch them

Comment: Remove layout_weight = 1 in the inside linearlayout and set its width to match_parent. otherwise it will take up the whole screen since the imageview has no weight. For the app name/label you could try looking into https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#loadLabel(android.content.pm.PackageManager) but I'm not fully sure.

Comment: I have written about starting an activity. What should I write in place of getPackageName() ?